# grunt-babel warning Binding 'arguments' in strict mode

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-babel

when I want to compress my javascript code with grunt and uglifyjs,but uglifyjs is not support es6,so I use grunt-babel, but I have meet some truble, it warning Binding 'arguments' in strict mode, so I write some simple code test it. In this file, the arguments is just a common local variable, is **not call(arguments) or apply**,I don't understand how it happend and how to fix it. 
here is the sample code:

```
'use strict';
let a = 1;
async function test() {
    return new Promise(resolve, reject => {
        let b = 1;
        let c = a + b;
        resolve(c);
    })
}

function no(arguments) {
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

then gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {  
  require("load-grunt-tasks")(grunt); 
  grunt.initConfig({  
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),       
      clean: {
        src: 'dist/'
      },
      copy: {
        main: {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'test',
          src: '**',
          dest: 'dist/',
        },
      },
      babel: {
          options: {
              sourceMap: false,
              presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
              ignore: ["/node_modules","./resources/vendor/**"],
              plugins: [
                  "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
                  ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs", { "strictMode": false }]
                ]
          },
          dist: {
              files: [{
                 expand:true,
                 cwd:'test/',
                 src:['**/*.js'],
                 dest:'dist/'
               }] 
          }
      },
      uglify: {  
          options: {
           mangle: true,
           comments: 'some'
          },  
          my_target: {
               files: [{
                 expand:true,
                 cwd:'dist/',
                 src:['**/*.js'],
                 dest:'dist/'
               }] 
          } 
      }
  });  

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-babel');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify'); 
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-usemin');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean','copy','babel','uglify']);
  }
```

then excute **grunt**
console log

```
Warning: F:\project\grunttest\test\test.js: Binding 'arguments' in strict mode (11:12)
```

I tried to configure babel options `["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs", { "strictMode": false }]` 
but it doesn't work,how can I fix it? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

as you can find in this link to the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

`arguments` is a reserved keyword within functions in javascript, which when you try to define it as the internal variable within the function `no` it is not able to bind it correctly, because `arguments` is this special object that contains all arguments to a function.

Just changing the name of the variable to another name will fix your error.